# ListView not displaying data in fragment using ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

i have a created a fragment in which i want to display listview but my fragment is dislplayed wtihout the listview nor i am getting an error

i have read many solutions to this question but i can't find the right one.
a small help would be great.thank you!

```
public class ServicesFragment extends Fragment {
    public TextView servicesName;
    ListView listView;
    String[] servicesNameArray;
    int[] serviceImages = {
            R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
            R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
            R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
            R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
            R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
            R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
            R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
            R.drawable.ic_menu_camera
    };
     public ServicesFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.services_fragment, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView_services);
        ServicesAdapter adapter = new ServicesAdapter(getContext(), servicesNameArray, serviceImages);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        Resources resources = getResources();
        resources.getStringArray(R.array.servicesName);
        return view;
    }

  public class ServicesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

 Context c;
        int[] servicesImageArray;
        String[] servicesNameArray;
        public ServicesAdapter(Context context, String[] servicesNameArray, int[] serviceImages) {
            super(context, R.layout.services_layout, R.id.listView_services);
            this.c = context;
            this.servicesImageArray = serviceImages;
            this.servicesNameArray = servicesNameArray;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.services_layout, parent, false);
            ImageView serviceImages = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_of_services);
            TextView servicesName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name_of_services);
            serviceImages.setImageResource(servicesImageArray[position]);
            servicesName.setText(servicesNameArray[position]);
            return view;}}}
```

Comment: make sure you pass desired data to your list adapter

Comment: yes i am passing it

Comment: where you fill servicesNameArray with data ?? it seem it passed empty

Comment: i have defined the array in the string.xml file and i am getting in the fragment using getResources()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not assigning value to the string array: use

```
servicesNameArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.servicesName);
```

and instead of :

```
 ServicesAdapter adapter = new ServicesAdapter(getContext(), servicesNameArray, serviceImages);
```

use the activity context:

```
ServicesAdapter adapter = new ServicesAdapter(this.getActivity(), servicesNameArray, serviceImages);
```

you need to notify you adapter about your data set size:

```
super(context, R.layout.services_layout, servicesNameArray); //change here
```

Comment: i know you by the way.....u have answered one of my question long time ago

Comment: Great!...**Always happy to help**

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue cause you dont pass data in correct way

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.services_fragment, container, false);
Resources resources = getResources();
        servicesNameArray = resources.getStringArray(R.array.servicesName);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView_services);
        ServicesAdapter adapter = new ServicesAdapter(getContext(), servicesNameArray, serviceImages);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }
```